# Any ideas why this does not work? C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
public class MyExample
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {


string input = "<a href=\"http://tvrss.net/search/?show_name=The+Venture+Bros&amp;show_name_exact=true\">The Venture Bros</a></p></li>";


    // Call Regex.Match
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, "/show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)</i");

   // Check Match instance
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Get Group value
        string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        // alternate-1
    }



    }
```

I want "The Venture Bros" as output (in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
string input = "<a href=\"http://tvrss.net/search/?show_name=The+Venture+Bros&amp;show_name_exact=true\">The Venture Bros</a></p></li>";

// Call Regex.Match
Match m = Regex.Match(input, "show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)</a");

// Check Match instance
if (m.Success)
{
    // Get Group value
    string key = m.Groups[2].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    // alternate-1
}
```

Comment: In other words, change the regex modifier from /i to /a, and take the third element of the match array instead of the second ("string key = m.Groups[2].Value").  Some explanation as to why this is better would increase the helpfulness of this answer, too.

Comment: No, that's not what he's doing. Exactly like I said, a lot of people are confused about the regex modifiers, they don't work like that in C#. He's not "changing the regex modifier", he's putting a literal "/a" on the end.

Comment: @Harleqin : code tells more then explanation. I read your comment 2 times and understand what you mean. But the code is obvious, You can see what you need to change.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're trying to do the perl-style slashes on the front and the end. A couple of other answerers have been confused by this already. The way he's written it, he's trying to do case-insensitive by starting and ending with / and putting an i on the end, the way you'd do it in perl.

But I'm pretty sure that .NET regexes don't work that way, and that's what's causing the problem.

Edit: to be more specific, look into RegexOptions, an example I pulled from MSDN is like this:

```
Dim rx As New Regex("\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The key there is the "RegexOptions.IgnoreCase", that'll cause the effect that you were trying for with /pattern/i.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the question mark before `show_name`. It is in input but not in pattern, thus no match.

Also, you try to match `</i` but the input doesn't contain this (it contains `</li>`).

Comment: I am tried this:

string input = "show_name=The+Venture+Bros&amp;show_name_exact=true\">The Venture Bros</a></p></li>";
...
Match m = Regex.Match(input, "/show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)</i");

So without the question mark in the input, but doesnt helped. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex in your case would be

```
^.*&amp;show_name_exact=true\"\>(.*)</a></p></li>$
```

regexp is tricky, but at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ you can find a great tutorial

Answer (score 1):

/?show_name=(.*)&show_name_exact=true\">(.*)

would work as you expect I believe. But another thing I notice, is that you're trying to get the value of group[1], but I believe that you want the value of group[2], because there will be 3 groups, the first is the match, and the second is the first group...

Gl ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think that a lot of people get confused and forget that group[0] is the entire string that is matched.

Answer (score 0):

First the regex starts "/show_name", but the target string has "/?show_name" so the first group won't want the first expected hit.

This will cause the whole regex to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break this down.

Test Data: `"<a href=\"http://tvrss.net/search/?show_name=The+Venture+Bros&amp;show_name_exact=true\">The Venture Bros</a></p></li>"`

Original Regex: `"/show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)</i"`

Working Regex: `"/\?show_name=(.*)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*)</a"`

We'll start at the left and work our way to the right, through the regex.

1. "?" became "\?" this is because a "?" means that the preceding character or group is optional. When we put a slash before it, it now matches a literal question mark.
2. `"(.*?)"` became `"(.*)"` the parentheses denote a group, and a question mark means "optional", but the "*" already means "0 or more" so this is really just removing a redundancy.
3. `"</i"` became `"</a"` this change was made to match your actual text which terminates the anchor with a `"</a>"` tag.

Suggested Regex: `"[\\W]show_name=([^><\"]*)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">([^<]*)<"`

(The extra \'s were added to provide proper c# string escaping.)

A good tool for testing regular expressions in c#, is the regex-freetool at code.google.com